# Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $A \subseteq X$. Show that the closure of $A$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $A \subseteq X$. Show that the closure of $A$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$.

**Definition 1.** Let $x \in X$. A set $N \subseteq X$ is called neighborhood of $x$ if there exists $U \in \tau$ such that $x \in U \subseteq N$. The set of all neighborhood of $x$ is denoted by $\mathcal{N}(x)$. Furthermore, $U$ is called open neighborhood of $x$ if $U \in \mathcal{N}(x) \cap \tau$.

**Definition 2.** Let $A \subseteq X$. A point $x \in X$ is called a closure point of $A$ if for any $U \in \mathcal{N}(x) \cap \tau, U \cap A \ne \emptyset$. The set of all closure points of $A$ is called a closure of $A$, denoted by $cl(A)$.

**Attempt:**
I want to show this only by using the definitions.

Let $A \subseteq X$. We want to show that:

1. $A \subseteq cl(A)$;
2. $cl(A)$ is closed; and
3. For any closed set $D$ with $A \subseteq D$, we have $cl(A) \subseteq D$.

By **Definition 2.**,
$$cl(A)= \{x \in X : (\forall U \in \mathcal{N}(x) \cap \tau).U \cap A \ne \emptyset\}.$$
Is it true? If yes, is it true that
$$cl(A)^c = \{x \in X: (\exists U \in \mathcal{N}(x) \cap \tau). U \cap A = \emptyset\}$$
be its complement?

For 1: Let $x \in A$. Let $U \in \mathcal{N}(x) \cap \tau$ be given.
By definition of $\mathcal{N}(x)$, there exists $U \in \tau$ such that $x \in U \subseteq U$.
Hence, $x \in U \cap A$ and so, $U \cap A \ne \emptyset$.
Therefore, $x \in cl(A)$. Thus, $A \subseteq cl(A)$.

For 2: We'll show that $cl(A)^c$ is open, i.e., $cl(A)^c \in \tau$.
Let $x \in cl(A)^c$. Then there exists $U \in \mathcal{N}(x) \cap \tau$ such that $U \cap A = \emptyset$. By **Definition 1.**, there exists $U \in \tau$ such that $x \in U \subseteq U \in \tau$. Hence, $cl(A)^c \in \tau$. Thus, $cl(A)$ is closed.

For 3: Let $D$ be any closed set with $A \subseteq D$. The goal is to show that $cl(A) \subseteq D$. Let $x \in cl(A)$. By definition, for all $U \in \mathcal{N}(x) \cap \tau$, we have $U \cap A \ne \emptyset$. Since $x \in U$ and $U \cap A \ne \emptyset$, then $x \in A$. Since $A \subseteq D$, then $x \in D$. Hence, $cl(A) \subseteq D$.

Therefore, by 1,2, and 3 above, we can conclude that $cl(A)$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$.

I'm in doubt whether my approach is correct. Any helps and corrections would be appreciated.
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about about step 2, and step 3 is definitely wrong. To be precise,

> Since $x \in U$ and $U\cap A \neq \emptyset$, then $x\in A$

is wrong.

---

Those steps can be proved almost at the same time:
$$
\operatorname{cl}(A)^c 
= \{x \in X: (\exists U \in \mathcal{N}(x) \cap \tau). U \cap A = \emptyset\}
= \bigcup \{U \in \tau: U \cap A = \emptyset\} 
$$

Last equality is manifestation of the following: if $x\in \operatorname{cl}(A)^c $
then exists $U \in \mathcal N(x) \cap \tau$ such that $U \cap A = \emptyset$. But then for any $y \in U$, we have $U \in \mathcal N(y) \cap \tau$ and thus $y \in \operatorname{cl}(A)^c $ giving $U \subseteq \operatorname{cl}(A)^c $. Because of that, we can omit everything about neighborhoods - any non-empty open set $U$ that satisfies
$U\cap A = \emptyset$ will be added on the sum, because it is neighborhood of something. We can throw in the empty set as well, since it does not contribute anything to the sum.

**Step 2**  is now trivial, because we have that $\operatorname{cl}(A)^c$ is sum of some family of open sets and therefore is open.

**Step 3** can be equivalently stated as $\operatorname{cl}(A)^c  \supseteq V$, where $V\in \tau$ satisfies $V \subseteq A^c$ or $V \cap A = \emptyset$.
Since complement of closure is sum of all such open sets, it naturally is the biggest one, and therefore closure is the smallest.

Comment: For 2, it's trivial by definition of $\tau$, isn't it? That is, the union of all collection of open sets is contained in $\tau$.

Comment: Also, did you mean $cl(A)^c=\bigcup \{U \in \mathcal{N}(x) \cap \tau: U \cap A=\emptyset\}$?

Comment: I added some clarification regarding your questions. Note that your family of open sets doesn't make sense, since you make reference to some arbitrary element $x$. I wrote everything correctly (see clarification).

Comment: Ok thanks Sir. ${}{}$